# Getting one column of SQLite DB to ListView not working in Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview

I'm trying to retrieve a column (a database column where names are saved) and puting them to a listview. I have a class called Data with "getters" and "setters".

The following code is placed in a DBHandler class which extends `SQLiteOpenHelper`. This code is called from the MainActivity.java where the listview is meant to be updated with an `onClickButton` event.

```
public String[] getNames (int a, int b) { 

        String[] names = new String[] {};

        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME 
                + " WHERE " + KEY_ONE + " = ? AND " + KEY_TWO + " = ?";


        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, new String[]{String.valueOf(a), String.valueOf(b)});

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

            int i = 0;

            do {
                Data myData = new Data();

                names [i] = cursor.getString(1); //Names in cursor

                ++i;

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());

        }
        return names;
    }
```

In the MainActivity.java I call the following code before updating and notifying the update of the listview adapter:

```
values = db.getNames (1, 1);
```

I don't know why but this isn't working, it throws many errors with String lengths and crashes the app when I click the button that is suposed to enter the onClickButton.

Thanks

Comment: Please upload those error logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String[] names = new String[] {};
```

...

```
names [i] = cursor.getString(1); //Names in cursor
```

You're assigning to an empty array which causes `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Consider using a list such as `ArrayList` where you can append your values, e.g.

```
List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
```

...

```
names.add(cursor.getString(1));
```

If you really need to return a `String[]`, you can convert the list with [`toArray()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/List.html#toArray%28T%5B%5D%29):

```
String[] arr = new String[names.size()];
names.toArray(arr);
return arr;
```

Also, when posting questions that involve exceptions, always include the exception stacktrace from logcat in the question itself.

Comment: How can I change that ArrayList to a String[] which is what I really need after all?

Comment: There's `toArray(T[] array)`

Comment: Is the other way, I need a String[] and I have an ArrayList

Answer (score 1):

Follow the **laalto** answer and at last convert your `ArrayList` to `Array` like below:

```
String[] arrRecords = names.toArray(new String[names.size()]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why use like this

```
 String[] names = new String[] {}; //no size

 names [i] = cursor.getString(1); //it can work?
```

Use `ArrayList<String>`

```
List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>(); //declare

names.add(<column-val>);  //add column value to list
```